# C++ #define in main, how to get other .cpp files to see it?

Tags: c++

Good afternoon all,

I'm writing a program to read license plates that has 11 files currently:

Main.cpp

DetectPlates.h
DetectPlates.cpp

DetectChars.h
DetectChars.cpp

PossiblePlate.h
PossiblePlate.cpp

PossibleChar.h
PossibleChar.cpp

Preprocess.h
Preprocess.cpp

I have a feature allowing showing the intermediate processing steps, or not.  Current this is implemented by having a global variable in Main.cpp as follows:

```
// global variables ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const bool blnShowSteps = false;
```

Then in DetectPlates.h and DetectChars.h, I have the following:

```
// external global variables //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
extern const bool blnShowSteps;
```

So in either DetectPlates.cpp or in DetectChars.cpp I can do something like the following:

```
if (blnShowSteps) {
    cv::imshow("1a", imgGrayscaleScene);
    cv::imshow("1b", imgThreshScene);
}
```

This is done many times in both DetectPlates.cpp and in DetectChars.cpp.  So far I have used a global variable as above because I was translating this from a Visual Basic.NET version where the conditional looked at the state of a check box on a form and a global variable was an easy translation to start with.

To make this more "C++ish" I would like to change the global variable to conditional compilation.  For example, in Main.cpp I would like to do:

```
#define SHOW_STEPS         // NOTE: comment this line out, or not, to show or not show steps
```

Then in DetectPlates.cpp or DetectChars.cpp:

```
#ifdef SHOW_STEPS
    cv::imshow("1a", imgGrayscaleScene);
    cv::imshow("1b", imgThreshScene);
#endif
```

The problem is how do I implement this?  If I #include "Main.cpp" in DetectPlates.h and/or DetectChars.h I get various errors depending on if I used a multiple include guard in Main.cpp or not, but either way I do not get a compile and also this violates the general practice rule of never including a .cpp file.

One possible answer seems to be adding another .h file, called "MyDefines.h" or similar, with only one line:

```
// MyDefines.h - single line .h file ??

#define SHOW_STEPS         // NOTE: comment this line out to not show steps
```

But this is not an elegant solution for at least two reasons, for one adding an additional .h file to add one line seems poor, and also that would take the #define SHOW_STEPS out of the beginning of Main.cpp where it would logically be.

Another possible solution would seem to be to add a Main.h file, with the function prototypes and other stuff that is at the top of Main.cpp currently, and then to also add the #define SHOW_STEPS line.  This is also not a very elegant solution either since I would be adding an entire .h file to add one line, most C++ programs do not have a Main.h file, and this would still remove #define SHOW_STEPS from being just above function main() where most people would intuitively look when figuring out the flow of the program.

Is there a way to do this where the "#define SHOW_STEPS" line would be in Main.cpp but still be seen in DetectPlates.cpp and DetectPlates.cpp?

Comment: A single-line h-file is better than a "single" line in all your cpp-files; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: BTW you can stick your existing declaration `extern const bool blnShowSteps` into a dedicated h-file, and continue using your global variable instead of replacing it by a compilation flag. Neither option is ideal, and only you can decide which is better. An advantage of a global variable is some flexibility: you can temporarily set it to 0 and later reset back to 1.

Comment: I would make the variable non-const so that you can switch diagnostics on or off at run time without having to rebuild the executable.  That will probably be more useful in the long term.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the helpful and constructive feedback.  In the end I decided that adding a Main.h and putting the #define there as well as some other config stuff was the best option available in C++.  If anybody is curious here is what I have so far, which is pretty close to complete at this point:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Cpp/tree/master/LicensePlateRecognitionOpenCV3Cpp

If anybody has any additional comments or suggestions as to how this could be done better I'm open to suggestion.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 5):

As you suspected - place the definition in a header file (.h), and include it wherever necessary.

Either that, or don't use compiler tricks, make a configuration class, and pass the configuration object into the relevant part(s) of the program.  Have the configuration class read from a file or be initialised in a relevant way.

Edit: Just to comment on, *"To make this more "C++ish" I would like to change the global variable to conditional compilation"*.  Both are pretty dodgy practises.  Decent code design is probably what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3):

If you introduce #defines to make your code more "C++ish", you're doing something very wrong.

You don't need to explictly remove the if's at all, the compiler can do this for you, given better circumstances. To start with, change your global variable from `extern` to `static` in a header.

...That should be enough. If in doubt, check the asm output.

Answer (score 1):

Make it be defined for your whole project. Like adding `-DSHOW_STEPS` to GCC command line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to keep this compiler independent, and I'd also like the source to be able to stand on its own without special compiler settings.  Any other way this could be done??

Comment: @cdahms then you probably would have to create a `config.h` file where you would place all configuration macro definitions and include in all files which needs it. Usually projects move all such definitions in separate configuration files and let the make system figure out which compiler is currently in use, which build target and how to parse definition list and pass it to compiler